# number format with fixed total digit

Tags: number-representation

How to get an output of number form of a given TOTAL digit?

For example, a total digit of 3, then one get

- `1.00` for `1.`
- `10.0` for `10.`
- `100.` for `100.`

and so on.

I try `NumberForm[1., 3]` but only get `1.`. Of course I can use `NumberForm[1., {1, 2}]` to get `1.00` but then for `10.` I need to use `NumberForm[10.,{2, 1}]` and for `100` I need to use `NumberForm[100., {3, 0}]`, which is not automatic and depends on the certain number i input. So is there any way to get an output of number format with a fixed TOTAL digits that does not depends on the specific input?

Comment: How many total digits do you need ?

Comment: 4 digits is enough for my current use. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `SetPrecision` in between.

```
f[z_] := NumberForm[SetPrecision[z, 4], 4];
f /@ {1/10, 1, 10, 100}
```

> {0.1000, 1.000, 10.00, 100.0}

It is one of the great miracles why this does not work for machine precision numbers.

Comment: `SetPrecision` is exactly what i want. Thanks. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful as `SetPrecision` returns the input rounded, hence a different number. That does not matter if you use that only for displaying purposes. Use the result of `SetPrecision` in further computation if you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

How about this ? I think this is what you want. Feel free to let me know if otherwise:

```
fixform[n_, dig_] := Module[{},
  NumberForm[
   n, {Length[IntegerDigits[Rationalize[n]]], 
    dig - Length[IntegerDigits[Rationalize[n]]]}]
  ]
```

n is the number and dig is the Total number of digits you want.

For example:

```
fixform[10., 4]

(* 10.00 *)

fixform[100., 4]

(* 100.0 *)

fixform[1., 4]

(* 1.000 *)
```